# Reading a variable into another Perl program

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am writing a Perl CGI code as shown below.

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl
     use warnings; 
     use CGI;
     my $q = CGI->new; 
     print $q->header;
     print "<html><head><title>Precheck</title></head>\n";
     @clients = $q->param('sel');
     print '<body>';
     # some operations
     print '</body>';
     print '</html>';
```

Now I want to use the value of `@clients` which was read using "sel" parameter in the previous program in my next program. Please Help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Next program is a Perl program that uses the value of @clients and does some operations ...

Comment: I have made some buttons which the user has to click. Previous Programs had some checkboxes with name "Sel" using which i accessed in @clients . But my current program will not generate checkboxes to access in my next program . Now I have to get clients array in my next program

Comment: @mpapec Pls suggest me a simple solution . I am new to Perl CGI

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "next program" you mean "Another program run through CGI that will be triggered by another HTTP request from the same browser":

You'll need to introduce some means to preserve state. That usually means HTTP cookies. The CGI module you are using has [built in support for handling cookies](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTTP-COOKIES).

Since you can only store strings in them, you'll need to serialize the data. [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) is a sensible format for storing arbitrary data structures as strings.

If you have a lot of data, you might reach the length limit of cookies and will need to look at using sessions instead. This involves storing the data on the server with an identification token, and then storing that token in a cookie so you can link the data back to the browser. There are various [modules on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI%3a%3aSession) for helping with sessions.